# Generating Gaussian Random Numbers without a Uniform Random Number Generator

Tags: algorithm, random, gaussian

I know many uniform random number generators(RNGs) based on some algorithms, physical systems and so on. Eventually, all these lead to uniformly distributed random numbers. It's interesting and important to know whether there is Gaussian RNGs, i.e. the algorithm or something else creates Gaussian random numbers. Much precisely I want to say that I don't want to use transformations such as Box–Muller or Marsaglia polar method to get Gaussian from Uniform RNGs. I am interested if there is some paper, algorithm or even idea to create Gaussian random numbers without any of use Uniform RNGs. It's just to say we pretend that we don't know there exist Uniform random number generators.

Comment: Why do you *want* to avoid a uniform distribution as your basis?

Comment: It's just interesting if there exist just Gaussian RNG. Then transformation goes from Gaussian to Uniform

Comment: A curios fact is that because of the Central Limit Theorem, it's possible to obtain a Gaussian-distributed random variable by summing several (10+) random variables sampled from almost *any* distribution. So for sure you don't need to use the uniform distribution as the basis.

Comment: I can imagine a use of the required algorithm - if we want to model the real measurements, we have to model errors as well and they are always Gaussian. And that part devours heaps of time.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted in answers/comments, by virtue of CLT some sum of any iid random number could be made into some reasonable looking gaussian. If incoming stream is uniform, this is basically [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution). Ami Tavory answer is pretty much amounts to using Bates in disguise. You could look at closely related [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), and at `n=12` or higher they look a lot like gaussian.

There is one method which is used in practice and does not rely on transformation of the U(0,1) - Wallace method (Wallace, C. S. 1996. "Fast Pseudorandom Generators for Normal and Exponential Variates." ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software.), or gaussian pool method. I would advice to read description [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch37.html) and see if it fits your purpose

Comment: In a fairly recent [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3114.pdf), R. P. Brent describes a vectorized implementation of the Wallace PRNG which is claimed to be significantly faster than a Gaussian PRNG based on Box-Muller (on a particular vector processor;I have my doubts whether these performance characteristics apply to high-performance processor in general).

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was new for me.

Comment: Why people tend to create U(0,1)? I know some reasons 1) High-dimensional MC integration 2) Simulations 3) Easy transformations to other RNGs with different distribution 4) Games and so on.. Why people do not think to create Gaussian RNGs and work with it, even when needed to transform to Uniform RNG. Maybe it's easy to create Gaussian RNG

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's a bit unclear what is your motivation for this, and therefore I'm not sure if the following answers your question.

Nevertheless, it is possible to generate (an approximation of) this without the specific formulas transforming uniform RNGs that you mention.

As with any RNG, we have to have some source of randomness (or pseudo-randomness). I'm assuming, therefore, that there is some limitless sequence of binary bits which are independently equally likely to be 0 or 1 (note that it's possible to counter that this is a uniform discrete binary RNG, so I'm unsure if this answers your question).

Choose some large fixed *n*. For each invocation of the RNG, generate *n* such bits, sum them as *x*, and return

*(2 x - 1) / √n*

By the [de Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Limiting_distributions) this is normal with mean 0 and variance 1.

Comment: Thank you. I've got your answer. So now we can use Box-Muller  transformation in opposite  way to get Uniform, right ?

Comment: @Narek We have started from the uniform 0-1 range, have you forgotten that? You can create N long uniform range of this much more simply - use every bit as a next bit of the number. So, n random bit will give you 2^n-1 long uniform range.